# HttpClient5 - Lot of APIs changed / removed

Tags: apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents, apache-commons-httpclient, apache-httpclient-5.x

I'm migrating my application to use HttpClient5 but its becoming miserable day by day. Many APIs removed and no proper documentation available to know alternatives. Stackoverflow/any other website/blogs always shows about answers related to httpcomponents4.x but those APIs no longer exist in HttpClient5. I'm putting all my queries / alternatives here. If anyone knows, please answer / confirm if those are correct implementations.

1. **Setting socket timeout on client: Removed `RequestConfig.custom().setSocketTimeout(socketTimeout).build()` API**. After lot of research, found that there is seperate SocketConfig class which need to set on `ConnectionManager`

   ```
    SocketConfig socketConfig=SocketConfig.custom()
                                    .setSoTimeout(Timeout.ofMilliseconds(10000))
                                    .build();

    BasicHttpClientConnectionManager connMgr=new BasicHttpClientConnectionManager(registry);
    connMgr.setSocketConfig(socketConfig);

    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
            .setConnectionManager(connMgr)
            .build();
   ```
2. **Setting default host.** Followed this [How does one set Default HttpHost Target in Apache HttpClient 4.3+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20157594/how-does-one-set-default-httphost-target-in-apache-httpclient-4-3) and found that we can override `determineRoute` in `DefaultRoutePlanner` but we cannot do this in httpclient5 as this method declared as `final` so cannot override. So i did this:

   ```
        HttpHost targetHost = new HttpHost(myHost,myPort);
        HttpRoutePlanner planner=new HttpRoutePlanner() {

            @Override
            public HttpRoute determineRoute(HttpHost var1, HttpContext var2) throws HttpException {
                HttpRoute route=new HttpRoute(targetHost);//default for all requests
                return route;
            }
        };
           CloseableHttpClient client=HttpClients.custom()
                .setConnectionManager(mgr)
                .setRoutePlanner(planner)
                .build();
   ```
3. **`HttpRequestBase` replaced with `HttpUriRequestBase`**  - on HttpRequestBase we were calling getRequestLine() to know the request details which is printing like below:

`POST https://url HTTPS/1.1`

But `getRequestLine()` API removed in HttpUriRequestBase, so i'm using like this:

`httpReq.getMethod()+" "+httpReq.getUri()`
but its not printing protocol even if i use `httpReq.getVersion()`

4. **There are no seperate `httpasyncclient` `httpcore-nio` libraries for `HttpClient5`**  - After research, found that everything is bundled in `httpclient5` and `httpcore5` - Now more struggle starts here. All below classes no longer exist.

```
SSLIOSessionStrategy 
NoopIOSessionStrategy
PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager
DefaultConnectingIOReactor
ConnectingIOReactor
IOReactorException
```

Dont know the alternatives for this yet. `IOReactorConfig` apis are not clear. In the demo examples, `IOReactorConfig` was set on `CloseableHttpAsyncClient` without SSLcontext examples. In my case as per existing code, they are using `IOReactorConfig` and `SSLContext` . Now not sure how to club these.

Please suggest if i'm doing correct or not.

Lot of others are there. Will update.

Comment: I recently switched my work automation tests project from Apache Client 4.5.10 to 5.2.1, and I was able to set literally all the configuration from old client in the new one, but yeah, it was pain in the a*s

Comment: the documentations are really poor.

Comment: There is zero accessible documentation about the rationale behind these extensive changes.  I'm not seeing any benefits, yet.  Just looking at them now since we are just now adopting Spring Boot 3 and I'm trying to fix all the deprecation warnings.  Why `HttpRequester` instead of `HttpClient`?   Also, I'm seeing a lot of redundant information passed into the execution API.  Easy to get conflicting information that way.  I presume changes are to better support async cases and/or HTTP2, WebSockets, etc?   But I'm not seeing the connection, yet.